# How to recall key in dictionary as variable in a different function in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Task asked to do was
1. month_temp(…): this function accepts a month (string) as an argument and returns a set of
all the uniquely observed temperatures, i.e., the temperatures with no replication

### and this is how i created the dictionary

```
yearly_temperature= {}
yearly_temperature['January'] = [23,23,23,21,21,23,23,22,22,23,23,23,22,22,22,23,23,23,22,19,22,23,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,22]
yearly_temperature['February'] = [23,22,26,26,26,27,27,27,26,26,26,27,27,3,26,26,27,26,26,26,27,26,26,26,26,26,26]
yearly_temperature['March'] = [19,18,18,18,23,21,31,33,33,22,19,18,18,18,4,5,31,33,19,18,19,18,18,18,23,21,31,33,33,22]
yearly_temperature['April'] = [40,17,17,17,19,19,18,19,22,22,19,19,18,19,23,17,19,5,18,19,17,19,19,18,19,22,22,19,19,18]
yearly_temperature['May'] = [1,19,19,18,19,22,22,19,19,18,36,35,22,22,22,19,33,27,6,23,22,22,19,22,23,23,22,22,19,19]
yearly_temperature['June'] = [33,23,19,18,19,22,22,19,19,18,36,35,22,22,19,19,18,22,19,19,8,36,22,19,19,18,36,35,22]
yearly_temperature['July'] = [23,23,23,23,23,33,33,33,22,22,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,9,19,19,18,36,35,22]
yearly_temperature['August'] = [18,23,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,22,19,19,18,36,35,49,15,19,18,36,35,22]
yearly_temperature['September'] = [18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,22,23,23,18,36,35,49,14,19,19,18,36,35,22]
yearly_temperature['October'] = [18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,22,23,23,22,22,33,22,19,19,19,19,18,36,35,22]
yearly_temperature['November'] = [18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,22,23,23,23,24,22,22,19,18,36,35,49,19,21,11]
yearly_temperature['December'] = [18,36,35,49,19,19,40,23,22,22,23,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,18,36,35,12,19,19,18,23,22,22,23]
```

---

now i need to find a way to relate the input for function below and the key corresponding to the input, so that the function below successfully recalls correct data from the month and do operations

def month_temp(??????????):
    unique_value = set(month)
    return unique_value

Answer (score 0):

You want the unique temperatures, given a month?

```
def month_temp(month):
    unique_value = set(yearly_temperature[month])
    return unique_value
```

Example call: `month_temp('January')`.